# Why importing wallet from file doesn't work?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, wallet-recovery, windows, wallet

I borrowed a Windows computer from someone and used `monero-wallet-gui` on it to create a wallet stored in the default location of `%USERPROFILE%\MONERO`.

I then copied the wallet directory from `%USERPROFILE%\MONERO` to my computer, but this time `monero-wallet-gui` complains the wallet password is invalid, whereas it still works on the borrowed computer.

I know this is not the expected way to recover the wallet. Why does it not work on my computer? Does `monero-wallet-gui` use Windows user session data for encrypting wallet files with passwords? Is there a way to recover the keys without borrowing the computer again? Both `monero-wallet-gui` versions are above 0.15 and the wallet was generated last Monday.

Comment: I put 400 monero yesterday on this wallet only to discover that I can t open it and that I won 't be able to borrow the computer I borrowed until next week.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the wallet cache (i.e. the file without extension) from the folder?

Comment: FWIW, creating a wallet on someone else's computer is reckless. Your secret keys are compromised. Anyway, are the two computers using different key mappings (ie, some letters are on different places on the keyboard) ? The wallet password depends only on the text you enter as passphrase, but the system can interpret keyboard input in different ways (for example if they're set to different languages). Also, if you used non 7 bit ASCII characters, the encoding may be different, though I think Windows pretty much always uses its little endian version of UCS-2.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE no it doesn t.

Comment: @user36303 key mapping are the same. Lanuguages are also the the same. The person I borrowed the computer from in unable to understand the difference between cryptocurrency and fiat. So nothing is compromised.

Comment: I don't suppose you changed the number of KDF rounds used to derive the encryption key from the password ? It's an obscure setting, but it would cause this if you don't use the same setting on both computers.